# How to attach to an active session with a specific window and run a cronjob?

Tags: cron, tmux

On my development setup I have an active session with multiple windows, I'd like to spit out the cronjob's output to this active session into a **specific window** .
I wrote in the crontab the command:

```
/bin/bash /home/user/backup.sh
```

so the backup script looks quite straightforward:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Setting up all environment variables:
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
export DISPLAY=:0;

tmux new-session -d -s <session-name> -n <window name>
tmux send-keys "/usr/bin/rsync /home/user/input /home/user/output/" ENTER
```

BUT the script writes the output to the currently active window in tmux, how do i make sure to output into **window name** i mentioned in the script?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you show us the cron command in question (ie. the `crontab` entry), and tell us where it normally sends its output?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I have elaborated, as you requested :) any suggestions?

Comment: `tmux new-session` starts a new session, but you're asking how to put the new process into an already-active session.  Which do you actually want?  What should happen if there isn't an active session when the cron job runs?

Comment: The session always exist from the moment I login into my system. i'd like to attach to the already-active session. is this the correct command in tmux?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for `tmux new-window`, with the `-d` option.  From [`tmux(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#new-window):

> **new-window** [**-adkP**
>   ] [**-c** start-directory
>   ] [**-F** format
>   ] [**-n** window-name
>   ] [**-t** target-window
>   ] [shell-command
>   ]
>
> [...]
>
> If **-d** is given, the session does not make the new window the current window.

So your script will need the single command:

```
tmux new-window -d -n <new_window_name> -t <existing_session_name>: /usr/bin/rsync ...
```

Note that there is a `:` after the session name.  For the `new-window` command, the `-t` option expects a target window (in the form `session:window`), not just a target session.

Comment: I have tried it on my system (I have Tmux 2.7 installed), and unfortunately it doesn't work :/
Do i need the sendkeys command too? I tried both and it failed :/

Comment: I've tested with 2.7 and 2.8.  Can you please expand on "doesn't work"?  Try running the command directly, without a script/cron, and see what error it gives.